# full_join but with condition on matching

Tags: r, dplyr

I am going to try to make this as simple as possible, I would like a `dplyr` solution if possible:

Let's say I have a `DataFrame` of 2 `columns` called `f1`. The 2 columns are the reference number of an event and the date_begin is the begin date of the event:

```
f1
       reference date_begin
1 01100144609598 2020-08-15
2 01100144692499 2020-08-12
3 01100144609598 2020-08-09
4 01100434045112 2020-08-26
5 01100434067379 2020-08-24
6 01100723546188 2020-08-16
```

I also have another `DataFrame` called `f2` with 2 `columns`. The 2 columns are the reference number of an event and the date_end is the ending date of the event:

```
      reference  date_end
1 01100144609598 2020-09-06
2 01100144692499 2020-08-10
3 01100434121179 2020-08-25
4 01100578756185 2020-08-17
5 01100578757962 2020-08-31
6 01100578846401 2020-08-16
```

I want to use a `full_join` by reference. That being said:

1. If there is an end date before there is a begin date I want an NA in stead of the begin date
2. The end date has to be > than the begin date
3. If there are 2 end dates for the same reference that are bigger than a begin date take the smallest end date
4. If there is a begin date with no end date the end date should have an NA

So in this reproducible example I should have an f3 that looks something like the following :

```
           reference date_begin date_end
    1 01100144609598 2020-08-15 2020-09-06
    2 01100144692499      NA    2020-08-10
    3 01100144692499 2020-08-12      NA
    4 01100434121179      NA    2020-08-25
    5 01100578756185      NA    2020-08-17
    6 01100578757962      NA    2020-08-31
    7 01100578846401      NA    2020-08-16
    8 01100144609598 2020-08-09      NA
    9 01100434045112 2020-08-26      NA
   10 01100434067379 2020-08-24      NA
   11 01100723546188 2020-08-16      NA
```

Comment: If you do `full_join(f1, f2, by = 'reference')` it has 10 rows. Why do you have 11 rows in your output? Also for point number 2 what happens when end date is not bigger than begin date?

Comment: I want 11 because reference 01100144609598, the first one has its end date after it's begin date and so the row of the f2 and f1 dataframe can be one. Full_join gives you 10 because the second reference number is the same, however the end is before the begin so they are not allowed to be on the same row.

When end date is not bigger it should be on the same row as begin date just like the first row in f3 in the example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Chuck P mentions, the conditions make this a bit complicated.  Rather than use `full_join`, I've first combined `f1` and `f2` and then transformed to "long" format.  We can then group by `reference` and sort by `date` to set up to use `case_when` to apply the conditions stated in the post or other conditions as needed.  The result is then transformed back to "wide" format to present as shown in the post. The code is

```
  library(tidyverse)
#
#  combine f1 and f2 and pivot to long format
#
   all <- bind_rows(f1,f2) %>%
         pivot_longer(cols = c(date_begin, date_end),
                      names_to = "type", values_to = "date",
                      values_drop_na = TRUE)
#
#  group by reference, sort by date, and then use 
#  case_when function to pair begin and end dates
#
   all <- all %>% group_by(reference) %>% 
                 arrange(date) %>% 
                  mutate(index = 1:n(),
                         index = case_when(
                                 type == "date_end" & lag(type, n = 1) == "date_begin" ~  lag(index),
                                 TRUE ~ index)) 
#
#  pivot back to wide format to format results as shown in post
#
   result <- all %>% pivot_wider(names_from =type, values_from = date) %>% mutate(index = NULL)
```

The result is

```
> result
# A tibble: 11 x 3
# Groups:   reference [9]
   reference      date_begin date_end  
    <chr>          <date>     <date>    
1 01100144609598 2020-08-09 NA        
2 01100144692499 NA         2020-08-10
3 01100144692499 2020-08-12 NA        
4 01100144609598 2020-08-15 2020-09-06
5 01100723546188 2020-08-16 NA        
6 01100578846401 NA         2020-08-16
7 01100578756185 NA         2020-08-17
8 01100434067379 2020-08-24 NA        
9 01100434121179 NA         2020-08-25
10 01100434045112 2020-08-26 NA        
11 01100578757962 NA         2020-08-31
```

where the results are sorted by date.

Comment: Ah, nice I had looked at pivot_longer but gave up in favor of my plodding three parter

Comment: Thank youy ! 2 characters sacrificed for the internet gods :)

Answer (score 1):

This is more complex than it first appears because of the conditional logic.  I broke it down into three steps that occur after we do the initial `full_join` to make `f3`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

f3 <- full_join(f1, f2)
#> Joining, by = "reference"

f3
#>         reference date_begin   date_end
#> 1  01100144609598 2020-08-15 2020-09-06
#> 2  01100144692499 2020-08-12 2020-08-10
#> 3  01100144609598 2020-08-09 2020-09-06
#> 4  01100434045112 2020-08-26       <NA>
#> 5  01100434067379 2020-08-24       <NA>
#> 6  01100723546188 2020-08-16       <NA>
#> 7  01100434121179       <NA> 2020-08-25
#> 8  01100578756185       <NA> 2020-08-17
#> 9  01100578757962       <NA> 2020-08-31
#> 10 01100578846401       <NA> 2020-08-16
```

Step 1 set aside the rows where we don't have to do anything because either the begin data or the end date is NA

```r
nothing_to_do <-
   f3 %>% filter(is.na(date_begin) | is.na(date_end))
```

Step 2 identify rows where we have a begin date after an end date like "01100144692499" for these we actually have to add a row and then adjust the rows.

```r
end_before_beginning <-
   f3 %>% filter(date_begin > date_end) %>%
   group_by(reference) %>%
   do (
      add_row(.,
              reference = .$reference,
              date_begin = .$date_begin,
              .after = 1)
   ) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   mutate(date_begin =
             case_when(
                !is.na(date_end) ~ as.Date(NA_character_),
                TRUE ~ date_begin
             ))
```

Step 3 identify rows with multiple beginnings same ending where we have to select the one with the shortest time space like "01100144609598"

```r
multiple_beginnings <-
   f3 %>%
   group_by(reference, date_end) %>%
   mutate(instances = n(),
          date_diff = date_end - date_begin) %>%
   filter(instances > 1) %>%
   mutate(date_end =
             case_when(
                date_diff != min(date_diff) ~ as.Date(NA_character_),
                TRUE ~ date_end
             )) %>%
   select(-instances, -date_diff)
```

Glue them all to together

```r
final_answer <-
   list(nothing_to_do, end_before_beginning, multiple_beginnings) %>%
   reduce(full_join)
#> Joining, by = c("reference", "date_begin", "date_end")
#> Joining, by = c("reference", "date_begin", "date_end")

final_answer
#>         reference date_begin   date_end
#> 1  01100434045112 2020-08-26       <NA>
#> 2  01100434067379 2020-08-24       <NA>
#> 3  01100723546188 2020-08-16       <NA>
#> 4  01100434121179       <NA> 2020-08-25
#> 5  01100578756185       <NA> 2020-08-17
#> 6  01100578757962       <NA> 2020-08-31
#> 7  01100578846401       <NA> 2020-08-16
#> 8  01100144692499       <NA> 2020-08-10
#> 9  01100144692499 2020-08-12       <NA>
#> 10 01100144609598 2020-08-15 2020-09-06
#> 11 01100144609598 2020-08-09       <NA>
```

Your data...

```r
f1 <- structure(list(reference = c("01100144609598", "01100144692499",
                                   "01100144609598", "01100434045112", "01100434067379", "01100723546188"), 
                     date_begin = structure(c(18489, 18486, 18483, 18500, 18498,
                            18490), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")


f2 <- structure(list(reference = c("01100144609598", "01100144692499", 
                                   "01100434121179", "01100578756185", "01100578757962", "01100578846401"), 
                     date_end = structure(c(18511, 18484, 18499, 18491, 18505, 
                          18490), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```